# Yet another mail merge trigger on new row added fron Google sheet filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that uses a filter function which shows certain rows from another sheet. I'm also using yet another mail merge add on on the first sheet to hopefully trigger an email for new rows.

It doesnt work as this add on only allows you to trigger on new Google form submits qattached to a sheet.

When i open the add-on manually it sends allí the emails juet fine Bécquer i configuren the form notification function

I'm wondering if there is a way  to programatically execute the add-on from an app script function. I tried creating one from the Google sheet macro recorder but it gives me an error when i execute. I Guess muy questiob is two fold.

First if it's possible to do this with yet another mail merge and second if i can open an add-on on a sheet from an app script function.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you are using? It's easier to understand if we see the code.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to trigger the funcitonality of a Sheets add-on from Apps Script unless the add-on's methods are [available for use as a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries). YAMM doesn't appear to have the add-on's library key publically available though, which makes this impossible. It unfortunately isn't possible to simulate selecting the menu item from within Apps Script either.